# Get Javascript document.write Data into variable and show it

Tags: javascript, innerhtml, document.write

I have a remote Javascript which allow us to output data using a function, which returns the data by `document.write(thedata)`.

See http://www.websnapr.com/implementations/. Here :

```
wsr_snapshot('http://URL', 'websnapr API Key', 'Size');
```

Function has `document.writed` the data at http://www.websnapr.com/js/websnapr.js. See source of this JS File.

Now I would like to store this Data(whatever is writed) into a variable and then assign it to some Div innerHTML.

I tried everything but it is just changing the page where I am implementing it. I do not want to change the page. It should not open new screen and write it. It should do it on same page and hence I want to store the document.write data by the function into a variable and use it in innerHTML of any DIV.

Answer (score 0):

You could rewrite document.write prior to including the script and change it back to the original afterwards:

```
<script>
   var oldwrite = document.write;
   var text = '';
   document.write = function(t) { text = t; }
</script>
<script src="jsfile"></script>
<script>
   document.write = oldwrite;
   //text now contains your text
</script>
```

Answer (score -1):

Why not just copy the javascript file to your web server, and modify it to store the data instead of writing it?

Comment: What a ridiculous comment.  I didn't take the time to read through their license agreement, but it's possible they allow something like that.  I looked at the javascript code, and all it does is send your data to the server and output the response.